# why text overwritten when screen rotate in edit text

Tags: android, android-edittext

Content of the password and mail field are overwritten after rotating the tablets. When write something into the email and password field, turn device to rotate the view, then password becomes visible at the email field (email texts was overwritten by password) but the password texts keep the same as before (password is invisible for sure).
It is really weird.

Furthermore, I did`t use the built in EditText, instead I custom the text field by extends Relativelayout which has a autoCompleteText and button. you can see the [code](https://github.com/haiwen/seadroid/blob/d07c5bb24f4688e01ef202b45da0dbc33fc47939/src/com/seafile/seadroid2/ui/CustomClearableEditText.java) below.

```
public class CustomClearableEditText extends RelativeLayout {

void initViews() {
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.clearable_edit_text, this, true);
    edit_text = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.clearable_edit);
    btn_clear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clearable_button_clear);
    btn_clear.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.INVISIBLE);
    clearText();
    showHideClearButton();
}
public void setEmailAddressAutoCompleteAdapter(ArrayAdapter<String> adapter) {
    if (adapter != null)
        edit_text.setAdapter(adapter);
}
public void setInputType(String type) {
    if (type.equals(INPUT_TYPE_EMAIL)) {
        edit_text.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS);
        edit_text.setHint("email");
    } else if (type.equals(INPUT_TYPE_PASSWORD)) {
        edit_text.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
        edit_text.setHint("password");

    }
}
```

}

And I used this custom control by following code

```
emailText = (CustomClearableEditText) findViewById(R.id.email_address);
    emailText.setInputType(CustomClearableEditText.INPUT_TYPE_EMAIL);
    passwdText = (CustomClearableEditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    passwdText.setInputType(CustomClearableEditText.INPUT_TYPE_PASSWORD);
```

you can see the complete code [here](https://github.com/haiwen/seadroid/blob/d07c5bb24f4688e01ef202b45da0dbc33fc47939/src/com/seafile/seadroid2/ui/activity/AccountDetailActivity.java)

I want to know why the text was overwritten when I rotate the device. Thanks in advance.

Comment: where did you declared your custom controls? in onStart()? e.g. custom emailText = (CustomClearableEditText) findViewById(R.id.email_address);

Comment: in OnCreate of the activity

Answer (score 0):

Use **android:configChanges** attribute in manifest.xml as per following

```
<activity
    android:name="com.RecordActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection|layoutDirection"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
</activity>
```

Comment: Sorry I didn\`t describe the question correctly. It is the text was overwritten, instead of switched. So does it handle that problem?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because when user rotates the phone whole `Activity` gets restarted.

First (easy) way is to make sure all your views have IDs assigned. Sometimes it helps and OS manages to restore instance.

Second (hard[er]) way is to save instance by yourself. Something like that:

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putString("textKey", mEditText.getText().toString());
}
```

And then restore state in onCreate() or onRestoreInstanceState():

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if(savedInstanceState != null) {
        mEditText.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("textKey"));
    }
}
```

If you want to understand the whole process try reading [this guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html) about `Handling Runtime Changes`.